# Ultra large element with small scale visually disappear yet is rendered on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm facing the following issue:

Having a large View with a very small scale, the element disappear visually yet is still rendered and can be seen in the inspector.

I don't understand why it disappear, and I would like to avoid it, I would like for the element to remain visible without having to change either the width of the element or the value of the scale.

I encounter this issue only on Android, on iOS it works seamlessly.

I have toggled the props 'renderToHardwareTextureAndroid', 'needsOffscreenAlphaCompositing', 'collapsable' on the View component, but it does not change the outcome.

I would like to know if I encountered a technical limitation or if there is a solution.

I provided a code snippet in the expo snack link below that reproduce the issue I'm facing.
https://snack.expo.dev/@michmichmich/widthscaleissue

While thanking you for any help provided.